# Filter folders in specific directory

Tags: powershell

Here is sample script :

```powershell
gci -path c:\ -re -force -ou folders | ? {$_.Attributes -eq "Directory"}
```

The output of this command is used for different purposes.
How can I filter all folders in a specific directory from my `$folders` variable? For example `c:\specificdirectory\*`

Comment: You want to exclude specific folder from the resulting list, or exclude specific folder and anything below it?

Comment: My variable $folders will list me all folders from c:\ because the path of my main command is set to c:\. My goal is extract all data only from c:\specificFolder without running a new commande for example gci -path c:\SpecificFolder -re -force

Comment: So you want to take the output of the command you have and of its results just show the data from `c:\SpecificFolder`? If that is the case you would not need to specify `-Recurse` or `-Force` again

Comment: Thank you Vikas it work. Your answer is deleted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to use existing data as supposed to running another `Get-ChildItem`? Makes sense since you would already have this information stored in a variable. So you are trying to get all directory in a given path, which in your case is `c:\`. You could do this in one of two ways. In order of preference

```powershell
# PowerShell 3.0 or later
$dataForLater = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Recurse -Force -Directory
# PowerShell 2.0 or earlier
$dataForLater = Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -Recurse -Force | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer}
```

We capture all of the folders in `$dataForLater`. So you need a subset of this information for other purposes? Lets use a small regex query to narrow down this data set without affecting to original

```powershell
$regexPath = [regex]::Escape("C:\temp\somefolder")
$specializedData = $dataForLater | Where-Object{$_.FullName -match "^$regexPath"}
```

Now you have two variables:

1. `$dataForLater` which has all the folders... and
2. `$specializedData` which is a sub set of `$dataForLater`

A simpler answer provided by Vikas Gupta would be to used string methods.

```
$specializedData = $dataForLater | Where-Object{$_.FullName.StartsWith("C:\temp\somefolder")}
```

Comment: Here is Vikas answer that work {$_.FullName.StartsWith("c:\specificfolder")} but he have deleted answer. Your answer work to. Thanks!

Comment: @Cavalli I deleted my answer because it wasn't that accurate.. After posting it I realized that `StartsWith` is **not** the most accurate approach. Reason being `C:\somefolder` and `C:\somefolderIDontWant` will both match using `StartsWith`.. You clearly want it to either be exact `C:\somefolder` or `StartsWith("C:\somefolder\")`.. I was going to come back to edit the answer after thinking through it (case sensitivity could also be an issue using `StartsWith`, hence `-match` may have been a better choice).. but got caught up in other things.. Great that you did get your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following - All you want to do is filter the objects like so -

```
$folders | Where-Object {$_.FullName.StartsWith("C:\SpecificFolder\", [System.StringComparison]::OrdinalIgnoreCase) -or $_.FullName -ieq "C:\SpecificFolder"}
```